Can I enter the US on an ESTA before the 30-day grace period on a J1 then exit to Canada and re-enter on my J1?
I have booked a contiki tour that starts on the 10th of July, but my J1 visa's 30-day grace period is the 15th of July (14th of August on my documents as the official start date of the course). I am trying to work out whether I can enter the US on an ESTA and do the tour then travel into Canada and re-enter the US on my J1 visa. The tour ends in early August, and I have seen on some of the posts here thar I may be able to do this. I would just have to prove in my entry interview I would be leaving.
Would travelling to Canada count as international travel and would it be possible to do this and re-enter on my J1 within the grace period? I have seen a lot about the visa waiver program, so would this be something I need to apply to to be able to do this?

Jasmine, can you please tell us how it worked out?

Travellers seeking to enter the US by air or sea pursuant to the Visa Waiver Program are required to hold an onward ticket, and the final destination of the onward ticket may not be a "contiguous territory or adjacent island", unless the traveller is a resident of said contiguous territory or adjacent island (8 CFR 217.2(c)(1)). Since Canada is a contiguous territory, you must hold an onward ticket to a country other than Canada, unless

you enter the US by land, or
you are a resident of Canada.

If you're not a resident of Canada—and you don't have any reason to visit Canada other than to go back to the US immediately (which seems to be the case from your question)—then perhaps you should just plan to go back to your country of residence after your cruise, instead of Canada. Then you can have the return ticket in hand when you enter the US for the first time, and there will be no problem with using the Visa Waiver Program (assuming you already got approval from ESTA).

The return portion of the round-trip ticket does not have to be booked within the 90-day period, however, so if she arrives in early July with a ticket to return to her country of residence in mis December, or even later, that would satisfy the round-trip ticket requirement.  There's no need to go all the way home to Japan or Australia or wherever to switch to J-1 status; Canada or Mexico would be just fine.
